# assert.fail(1, 2) does not show deprecation warning for node.js 10

Tags: javascript, node.js

According to the [doc](https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html#deprecations_dep0094_using_assert_fail_with_more_than_one_argument), `assert.fail(1, 2)` should show deprecation warning. It does for the REPL, but for files it does not.

index.js

```
require('assert').fail(1,2);
```

and then

```
$ node index.js
```

does not show the warning.

I would like to see them. I've tried several command line options but they seem to have no effect.

My node is of version 10.